# Is it possible to redefine "." using macros in C?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have a (possibly faulty) school assignment regarding the C-preprocessor, in which I should essentially define a macro which allows

```
Today is the 9.
```

to compile to

```
int a = 9;
```

Note the "." after the 9. The rest of the program is similar, I have no problem with that.

Now I replaced "Today" by `int` (`#define Today int`), "is" by `a`, "the" by `=` but I don't know what to do with the ".", given if I just blindly replace it by doing

```
#define . ;
```

I get a compile-time error.
Is it even possible to do something with the dot?

Comment: Please add the exact assignment wording.

Comment: your school's teacher needs to be fired for that assignment.

Comment: Ask him to do this with: `Today is the 9th.`

Comment: 9. is a float. It will be converted to int on assignment.

Comment: @Raildex I know what you mean. But on the other hand, maybe the homework is meant to teach via failure. Finding out the hard way that pre-processor can NOT magically do any imaginable replacing I would consider a valuable lesson. Quite hard though...

Comment: I think you need to speak more to the teacher and ask for clarification.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It's a text formatted in a "cody" way which among others, contains this line. All the others are no issue, it's really like an impractical way to mess around with #define a little bit.

Comment: Please show the next line (the one after "Today ...". I suspect we could get the "." ignored (as part of the float 9.) and then sneak in the needed ";" at the start of the next line.

Comment: but the point isn't supposed to mean a float but an actual dot used in English to end the sentence. I wrote an email to my teacher, let's see what he answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to redefine "." using macros in C?

No.

> given if I just blindly replace it by doing
>
> ```
> #define . ;
> ```
>
> I get a compile-time error. Is it even possible to do something with
> the dot?

No, it is not possible.

In the first place, the `.` in the text presented is not a separate token according to C's rules.  It is part of `9.`, a floating-point constant.  Macro replacement operates only on complete tokens.

In the second place, macro replacement is not a general search / replace.  Macro names must be C identifiers, which start with either an underscore or a Latin letter, and contain only underscores, Latin letters, and decimal digits. Thus, it is not possible to define either `.` by itself or the full `9.` as a macro name.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define Today int
#define is a
#define the = (int)


void foo(void)
{
    Today is the 9.;

    printf("%d\n", is);
}
```

Comment: I believe this will not pass the homework, because of the still present `;`.

Comment: Looks like you are replacing in the other direction.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Looks like the same direction as OP tries.

Comment: @Yunnosch Hmm it looks like OP is giving contradictory statements about what should be replaced by what.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I can read it consistently "Replace int by Today (etc.) in the code and then use prepro magic to make it still compile." This is supported by the **"it should compile"**. If "int" is kept in the code and the preproed into Today (etc.) it will surely not compile. But I know what you mean. Which is why I "agreed" with the HolyBlack commet and close-voted for lack of details.

Comment: Exactly what @Yunnosch says, I would be totally fine without the "." and finished with the assignment.

Comment: @0___________ What's the difference between `#define the = (int)` and `#define the int`